# iOS 14 dequeueReusableCell issues

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, user-interface, ios14

I have a chat view where I'm using tableview to display different custom cells for incoming and outgoing messages and the app was working fine till ios 13,

But as soon as I updated the phone OS to ios 14 its giving me issue

the issue is seems to be likely in dequeueReusableCell function, bigger cells taking height if smaller cells and smaller taking height of bigger cell instead of their own cell content

I have used the table height like this

**IN VIEW DIDLOAD FUNCTION**

```
    self.chatTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44
    self.chatTableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension

internal func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableView.automaticDimension
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableView.automaticDimension
}
```

Also tried to use

```
cell.setNeedsLayout()
cell.layoutIfNeeded()
```

at differenct places like when the heightForRowAt, cellForRowAtIndexPAth and willdisplayCellForRowAtIndexPAth get called but getting the same issue

[image: Issue Image]

Comment: First, if you're using auto layout, you can remove the delegate methods where you're simply returning `UITableView.automaticDimension` anyways. Secondly, you could try setting the vertical content hugging priority on the text labels to high like this `yourCellsTextLabel.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .vertical)`

Comment: I have tried both the points that you have mentioned but still the same issue, as soon as the new cells are creating while scrolling they just took the size of current presented cells